# How does the Scrapy Downloader work?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Please have a look at the following link for Scrapy Architecture.

https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/architecture.html#component-downloader

I do not understand the point 5.

> Once the page finishes downloading the Downloader generates a Response (with that page) and sends it to the Engine, passing through the Downloader Middlewares (see process_response()).

Does it mean that it downloads/loads the whole of the page in our System(RAM) because the size of the page is bigger than the Response(HTML)?

Please see the point 6.

> The Engine receives the Response from the Downloader and sends it to the Spider for processing, passing through the Spider Middleware (see process_spider_input()).

Please correct me if I am wrong anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. When it talks about downloading the page, it's just talking about the one thing returned in that request (it might be html, or it might be a jpg... depends on the site and you spider). The difference between the HTML and the response that contains the HTML is the response also contains a lot of additional information the came with the HTML. It will have the error code (probably 200, if all went well), cookies, or any other headers the server might have returned.

Where you might be interested in downloader middlewares is things like, for example checking a site for 404 errors. Normally those are filtered by the downloader middleware, so if you want your spider to deal with them (in my case, I wanted to log them. The spider I wrote was to check my site for erroring pages so I could respond quickly to things).

If you are interested in, for example, the images, you need to have your spider then create a new request for them.

It's hard to tell from your post, but it sounds like your concern is memory footprint. The docs present some good idea for trying to debug memory/reference leaks. https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/leaks.html

Comment: thanks for your reply . i do not understand one thing, when we browse the url then page is executed on sever side and we get the rendered html. My question is how/where downloader executes the page. I am sorry if i could not able to throw my question properly in my actual post

Comment: If your spider requests an HTML page, it will be generated and sent to you by the server side exactly as if it had been requested from the browser (exempting that the site may do User Agent checking, although that's evil). When the page is sent to you by the server, it only sends the html. That HTML is the processed by the client (be it spider or browser) which proceeds to request any additional content it needs (like images). This is not done server-side but client-side. It just happens quickly enough that you may not notice it.